# Delete file from database error

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try {
     Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\AhzelBrend\\Documents\\Student.mdb");
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

     String Query = "DELETE FROM StudentTable WHERE FULLNAME='"+ List1.getSelectedValue()+ "'";
     stmt.execute(Query);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Deleted");
     FillList();
     IKlir();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)  {
        Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
       }
    catch(SQLException ex){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: and short description what thing did not happen and what did.

Comment: when i press the button delete it shows the messagedialog "record deleted", but on list1 it didnt delete. same in database it didnt delete. please help im noob in java.

Comment: Do a `commit` after you execute your statement and close the connection

Comment: can u give me example thanks for helping.

Comment: Use `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)` for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE it will return number of affected rows, check if it is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: @jayson At the end of your try-block write `conn.commit(); conn.close();`

Comment: conn.commit(); conn.close(); didnt work sir.. on my list1 the name is still there.

Comment: Sorry - wrong place for the code. Place it behind `stmt.execute`. I think `FillList` refresh your list? And please use `stmt.executeUpdate` (see the comment from  Karthikeyan Vaithilingam) and check the return value.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam how to know if it is greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: Use an if condition.

Comment: @drkunibar can you give me your email address. i will pass to you all the project so that you can able to debug the error . thanks.

Comment: i am using netbeans 8.0.2 JFrame

Comment: @jayson - Sorry, I will not publish my email address here. But you can create a simple example with only a `public main(String[] args)` method, console output and a In-Memory database like derby or h2-database.

Comment: my brain is bleeding now.  huhu. tomorrow is the date of passing the project.. i am a student

Comment: @drkunibar may i ask you a question. why netbeans 6.9 didnt run on my computer 64bit windows 8.1 pro . it only show the splash then nothing happen. whats wrong in my pc.

Comment: @jayson - I don't know. I use Linux Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with your Database and have a look at the output. You can change a bit and test it with your database. Hope that helps

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DbTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Your MS Access driver
            // Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            // My Test H2 driver
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

            // Your MS Acess connection
            // Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\AhzelBrend\\Documents\\Student.mdb");

            // My H2 connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // Create and fill database
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE StudentTable (FULLNAME VARCHAR(255))");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO StudentTable(FULLNAME) VALUES ('Name " + i + "')");
            }

            // Your delete statement
            // String Query = "DELETE FROM StudentTable WHERE FULLNAME='"+ List1.getSelectedValue()+ "'";
            // My delete statement
            String Query = "DELETE FROM StudentTable WHERE FULLNAME='Name 5'";
            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(Query);
            System.out.println(rows + " rows affected");
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();

            // Open a new Connection to test th result
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM StudentTable");
            // Stundent 'Name 5' has been deleted
            while (results.next()) {
                System.out.println("Student " + results.getString("FULLNAME"));
            }
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Deleted");
            // FillList();
            // IKlir();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @jayson - Does it mean that it works with your MS Access database? Then the problem is in your `FillList()` method